# Error code = 0x80070002 in visual studio c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I just installed visual studio, (not new to coding) and I keep getting an error that goes like "error: unable to open file C:user...main.obj Error code = 0x80070002" 
[an Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYz8X.jpg)
this error shows up whenever there is something wrong with my code like for example if i do:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

everything runs normal, but if I make a mistake say:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
std::cout std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

I get the error, it's so annoying I don't want to get that error every time there is something wrong with my code the error list bar is enough, what do I do ?

Comment: Never seen that error before. Have you done something weird like put your object files under source code control?

Comment: if you google `0x80070002` there are some hits that talk about an incomplete windows update.

Comment: You may want to try a clean build. Even delete the Debug folder completely. Or does this happen on any project?

Comment: check if `Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Debugging -> Generate Debug Info` is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please tell us what version of Visual Studio are you using?

If you are using vs2017 or later, I suggest you could try to use `/DEBUG:FULL` property in "Linker/Debugging/Generate Debug Info.

[image]

I suggest you could refer to the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/debug-generate-debug-info?view=vs-2019):

> When you specify /DEBUG with no additional options, the linker
>   defaults to `/DEBUG:FULL` for command line and make file builds, for
>   release builds in the Visual Studio IDE, and for both debug and
>   release builds in Visual Studio 2015 and earlier versions. Beginning
>   in Visual Studio 2017, the build system in the IDE defaults to
>   `/DEBUG:FASTLINK` when you specify the /DEBUG option for debug builds.
>   Other defaults are unchanged to maintain backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the program in a different disk or reinstall the VS could be the final solution I think.